# Access variable in Gridview function yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I am trying to access a variable on view file into `Gridview` but it is throwing error that `it should be array but null given` i am declaring `$totalDays` on top of my view file and i am using it in `Gridview` like below

```
[
            'attribute' =>  'class_id',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'label' => "Class Date",
            'value' => function ($model) {
                array_push($totalDays,$model->class->date);
                return $model->class->date;
            },
            'footer'=> '<span>Total Days</span>',
],
```

But it throws following error

> array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: This will answer your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241336/yii2-pass-variable-from-view-to-gridview-custom-action-columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To explain, `$totalDays` is not available in the widget because the whole function only gets run when the widget is rendered, `$totalDays` is no longer declared. As @arogachev hinted above, you will need to make `$totalDays` in your model, then you can access it. Try this in your model;

```
public function getTotalDays(){
//Your logic here to generate totalDays
return $totalDays;
}
```

Then you can use it in your view like this;

```
[
    'attribute' =>  'class_id',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'label' => "Class Date",
    'value' => function ($model) {
        array_push($model->totalDays, totalDays,$model->class->date);
        return $model->class->date;
    },
    'footer'=> '<span>Total Days</span>',
],
```

Comment: this makes sense and easy to implement. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Insert `use` after function signature in `value` callable function:

```
[
            'attribute' =>  'class_id',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'label' => "Class Date",
            'value' => function ($model) use($totaleDays) {
                array_push($totalDays,$model->class->date);
                return $model->class->date;
            },
            'footer'=> '<span>Total Days</span>',
],
```

Answer (score 3):

As [@Fabrizio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2314488/fabrizio-caldarelli) said. Insert `use` after function signature in `value` callable function:

```
'value' => function ($model) use($totaleDays) {
    array_push($totalDays,$model->class->date);
    return $model->class->date;
},
```

For multiple value to pass in to value function you can use as below.

```
'value' => function ($model) use($var1, $var2....., $varN) {
    array_push($totalDays,$model->class->date);
    return $model->class->date;
},
```

Like this `use($var1, $var2....., $varN)`

Comment: This post save my life :)

Answer (score 2):

While you can definetely pass this variable through `use` section of closure, it's wrong in your code. MVC principle is violated, because view it's only for display, and you exposing logic such as `array_push`.

I'd recommend to refactor it and place data calculation in model, so you can simply call `return $model->yourMethod();` and it will return desired data.

Comment: ok. So you suggest that i should not use functions on the view page and instead just call it from controller or model...